# Angular in-memory-web-api method always returns 404 NotFound in the brower's console even if the tests passed

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, angular-test

I'm new to unit testing in Angular (using Jasmine and Karma)

I'm trying to create some tests for my httpService, apparently the tests are OK.

[image]

But sometimes when I either run `ng test`, or refresh the browser, I found that one of the test in one of the 3 test suites has failed with this message : `Uncaught [object Object] thrown`.

[image]

Another annoying thing is that no matter whether all of the tests pass or any of them fail, if you check the browser's console, you'll ALWAYS find this message :

[image]

[I'm attaching the code in a zip file (uploaded to Drive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w_VDP5CbY7p5o9LlpogfpcAl6gvnBh8D/view?usp=sharing). You only need to run `npm install` and `npm start`.

I really hope you can help me understand why this testing behaves like a Russian roulette.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `calculator.component.spec.ts`. You are not mocking `loanService` where it is going out and making `HTTP` calls. You should always mock external services.

Change `calculator.component.spec.ts` to:

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { CalculatorComponent } from './calculator.component';
import { LoanService } from '../loan.service';
import { Campaign } from '../campaign';
import { of } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/of';

describe('CalculatorComponent', () => {
  let component: CalculatorComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CalculatorComponent>;
  let mockLoanService: any;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    // mockLoanService object, first parameter ('loanService') is optional, second paramter => array of methods needing
    // mock for component
    mockLoanService = jasmine.createSpyObj('loanService', ['getCurrentCampaign', 'getMonthlyAmount']);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ CalculatorComponent ],
      imports: [],
      // NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA to ignore child components, if you need the
      // painting of the DOM of the child components/directives, put them in declarations
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        FormBuilder,
        // provide the mock for LoanService
        { provide: LoanService, useValue: mockLoanService },
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CalculatorComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    // getCurrentCampaig is related to ngOnInit so we have to mock it
    mockLoanService.getCurrentCampaign.and.returnValue(of({
      id: 1,
      campaign_name: 'Donald Trump 2020',
      min_quota: -200000000,
      max_quota: 0,
      max_amount: 0,
      min_amount: 0,
      tea: 1,
      payment_date: new Date(),
      currency: 'Fake News',
    } as Campaign))
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I have written some comments in the file itself. By the way, `Donald Trump 2020` and `Fake News` are just jokes, I have no political affiliation but I like writing jokes in my unit tests for other developers :).

Some notes:

1.) Whenever you are injecting a service, always mock it. You are testing the component and component alone, you have to assume that the service will do its job because it is already being tested.

2.) Check out `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`. It basically ignores all components/directives in your HTML that is not in the `declarations` array. If you are writing a test where you click the button of a child component and it affects this component, then declare it in `declarations` (basically if you need the actual implementation of the child component, declare it). Otherwise, use `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`.

3.) Importing `SharedModule` in all unit tests is not good in my opinion. It will make your unit tests slow. Instead, take advantage of `declarations` and `providers` and give the component what it needs and JUST what it needs (not extra stuff).

4.) A really good class in PluralSight called Unit Testing in Angular.
Taking that class, you will have a better understanding of Unit/Integration testing. Maybe buy a subscription to PluralSight or start a free trial.